# Incorrect page number in response while using Spring Boot with one-indexed-parameters: true

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

I'm using Page and Pageable in my Spring Boot web application — my controllers receive Pageable argument and pass it through the whole application to Mongo repositories in order to obtain Page. Since my frontend pagination starts from 1 (Spring Boot pagination starts from 0 by default) I've configured Boot to start pages from 1 by setting 
`spring.data.web.pageable.one-indexed-parameters=true`
in application.properties. Though page request indexes are synchronized between frontend and backend now, Spring Boot response contains zero-indexed page number. In order to make it clear: you'll receive page 1 if you request page 1 but field "number" of this page will have value 0. Is there any workaround to this issue?

Comment: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-commons/issues/1032 
There is no WA